# Overriding getView of ArrayAdapter to fill 3 Textviews

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

From my Activity, I am calling my `MovieTask` that extends`AsyncTask`.
I get Json response from the server which I have successfully parsed inside the `doInBackground` method of `MovieTask`.

Now, I have a listview in my activity and I want to populate the listview using `MovieListAdapter` that extends `ArrayAdapter`.

For every view (i.e. a row), I want to fill 3 `TextView`s. I am overriding `getView` method of `MovieListAdapter` to fill the same. 
But I don't understand how to send the data to `getView` method from my activity to `getView` method to populate the textviews?

```
public class MovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{        

    @Override
    protected String  doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //I HAVE GOT THE JSON DATA THAT CONTAINS AN ARRAY..
        //EACH ENTRY IN ARRAY SHOULD BE FILLED IN A SINGLE ROW IN LISTVIEW

        getMovieDataFromJson(result);
    }

    private void getMovieDataFromJson(String JsonString) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JsonString);
        JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

        for (int i=0; i<results.length(); i++){
            String title = results.getJSONObject(i).getString("original_title");
            String date = results.getJSONObject(i).getString("release_date");
            long id = results.getJSONObject(i).getLong("id");
            double vote = results.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("vote_average");


             //HERE I NEED TO CALL THE GETVIEW METHOD SO THAT IT FILLS THE ROW OF THE LISTVIEW WITH THESE VALUES - title, date and vote
        }
}
```

MovieListAdapter.java

```
    public class MovieListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String > {
    public MovieListAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // I NEED TO PREPARE EACH ROW OF LISTVIEW HERE
       //EVERY ROW CONTAINS 3 TEXTVIEWS WHICH I NEED TO FILL
       //BUT HOW DO I SEND DATA TO FILL THE TEXTVIEW ?
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `setAdapter()` on an `AdapterView` for example `ListView`, `getView()` is called internally and the views returned from the same are populated in the `AdapterView`.

You might want to read and learn about how `AdapterView`s and `Adapter`s work. Go ahead and read some docs here:

- [Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)
- [Custom ArrayAdapter for a ListView](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/)
- [Grid View and Adapter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

What you need to do is:

- Create a model for your data like:

  ```
  public class Movie {
      public long id;
      public String date;
      public String title;
      public double vote;

      public Movie(long id, String date, String title, double vote) {
          this.id = id;
          this.date = date;
          this.title = title;
          this.vote = vote;
      }
  }
  ```
- Create a layout to show movie details like:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lbl_date"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lbl_title"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lbl_vote"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- Change your adapter to handle `Movie`s rather than `String`s like:

  ```
  public class MovieListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie > {
      public MovieListAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> objects) {
          super(context, 0, objects);
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          if (convertView == null) {
              convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_item, parent, false);
          }

          ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_date))
                  .setText(getItem(position).date);

          ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_title))
                  .setText(getItem(position).title);

          ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_vote))
                  .setText(String.valueOf(getItem(position).vote));

          return convertView;
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally set the adapter after your for loop like:

  ```
  private void getMovieDataFromJson(String JsonString) throws JSONException {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JsonString);
      JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

      ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int i=0; i<results.length(); i++){
          String title = results.getJSONObject(i).getString("original_title");
          String date = results.getJSONObject(i).getString("release_date");
          long id = results.getJSONObject(i).getLong("id");
          double vote = results.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("vote_average");

          movies.add(new Movie(id, date, title, vote));
      }

      myMoviesListView.setAdapter(new MovieListAdapter(MainActivity.this, movies));
  }
  ```

Comment: Got it :) Thank you sir !!