# How to strike specific text in Spinner android?

Tags: android, spinner, strikethrough

I want to strike specific text in Spinner, My code look like below code

```
    packSpinner = findViewById(R.id.packSpinner);
    String spinnerArray[] = new String[10];

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
      spinnerArray[i] = packArray[i] + mrpArray[i] + sellingPriceArray[i];
    }

    packSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),                 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, spinnerArray));
```

In above code products coming from server and i already extracted that data into packArray, mrpArray and sellingPriceArray, now i want to mrp text should be striked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `StrikethroughSpan` or just set `textView.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);` but for both you must have access to `TextView`, so you can't achieve your purposes with defaut `ArrayAdapter`, it was designed to show simple lists without custom effects (most common usage). you have to extend it and override `getView` method. some examples [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177056/overriding-android-arrayadapter), [HERE](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211061/overriding-getview-of-arrayadapter-to-fill-3-textviews)

Answer (score 0):

**You can do using**

```
textview.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

**Adapter Specific location**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.spinner_text, list) {
                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    if (position == 0) {

                        return false;
                    } else {
                       
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView textview = (TextView) view;


                    if (position == 0) {
                        textview.setPadding(0, 0,0,0);
                        textview.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(RegistrationActivity.this,R.color.textColor_gray));
                        textview.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                    } else {
                        textview.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.paddingformleft), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.paddingform), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.paddingform), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.paddingform));

                        textview.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(RegistrationActivity.this,R.color.dark_light_txtColor));
                    }



                    return view;
                }
            };

            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_text);
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```